# Alter table field's attribute value to UNSIGNED - Mysql laravel migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration, lumen

Trying to alter table 'role_user' to change the field 'user_id' attribute to 'unsigned' to add a foreign key constraint

```
 Schema::table('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->change(); 
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Is it right way to change field's attribute value?

I am getting runtime exception `'Changing columns for table "role_users" requires Doctrine DBAL';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the following package:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

DABL package from doctrine allow you to modify columns.
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/introduction.html

Also check out modifying column section:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations

It's mentioned right there:

> Before modifying a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your composer.json file. The Doctrine DBAL library is used to determine the current state of the column and create the SQL queries needed to make the specified adjustments to the column: